# Spark convert milliseconds to UTC datetime

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I've got a dataset where 1 column is a `long` that represents milliseconds. I want to obtain the timestamp (`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`) that this number represents in **UTC**. Basically I want the same behaviour as https://currentmillis.com/

[image]

My question is, is there a way to have Spark code convert a milliseconds long field to a timestamp in UTC? All I've been able to get with native Spark code is the conversion of that long to my local time (EST):

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

sc = SparkContext()
spark = SQLContext(sc)

df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([{'millis':1582749601000}]))

df.withColumn('as_date', F.from_unixtime((F.col('millis')/1000))).show()

+-------------+-------------------+
|       millis|            as_date|
+-------------+-------------------+
|1582749601000|2020-02-26 15:40:01|
+-------------+-------------------+
```

I've been able to convert to UTC by forcing the timezone of the whole Spark session. I'd like to avoid this though, because it feels wrong to have to change the whole Spark session timezone for a specific use case within that job.

```
spark.sparkSession.builder.master('local[1]').config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC").getOrCreate()
```

I would also like to avoid custom defined functions as I want to be able to deploy this in Scala and Python, without writing language-specific code in each.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use **`to_utc_timestamp`** to specify your timezone(**`EST`**).

```
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    df.withColumn("as_date", F.to_utc_timestamp(F.from_unixtime(F.col("millis")/1000,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'EST')).show()

    +-------------+-------------------+
    |       millis|            as_date|
    +-------------+-------------------+
    |1582749601000|2020-02-26 20:40:01|
    +-------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! `from_utc_timestamp` reutnrns 10:40:01, but `to_utc_timestamp` returns 20:40:01, which is what I want. You could change that on your answer.

Also, do you know if there's a way to dynamically grab the locale's timezone? I would like to avoid hardcoding `EST`, as this will get deployed in a cluster, in which the timezone could be change over time.

Comment: on my databricks cluster, doing your code `df.withColumn('as_date', F.from_unixtime((F.col('millis')/1000))).show()` returns `20:40:01`. i guess u have tweeked ur spark settings for timezone?

Comment: Ugh... more the reason to have that timezone dynamically injected and not hardcoded

Comment: @murtihash: I want to convert epoch time to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
I tried below but work. the miliseconds part comes as .000

srcdf.withColumn("srcPublishedTime",from_unixtime(col("publishedTimestamp"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))